# mongo db text search on an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am setting up a mongo db test search on my API on the `location` object in my model below.
I get an error when trying to set up my text search in the DB like below. Please what could be the issue?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const placeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    location: {
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        street: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        city: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        state: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        zip: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
    price: {
        currency: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        amount: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }
    img: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
        default: false
    },
    phone: {
        code: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        number: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        }
    },
})

placeSchema.index({ location.country: 'text', location.street: 'text', location.city: 'text', location.state: 'text', location.zip: 'text' })


const Place = mongoose.model('Place', placeSchema)

module.exports = Place
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try this helper function.

You can pass search word as a first parameter and Array of fields for search as second parameter.

```
module.exports.searchHelper = function (searchWord, fields) {
    let orArr = [];
    let search = searchFiled.split(" ");
    fields.forEach((element1) => {
        search.forEach((element) => {
            orArr.push({ [element1]: { $regex: new RegExp(element, "i") } });
        });
    });
    return { $match: { $or: orArr } };
};
```

now you have to aggregate this in pipeline:

```
let fieldsArray = ['location.country','location.city','location.state'] //as per your need

let pipeline = [];

pipeline.push(searchHelper(searchWord, fieldsArray));

const results = await Place.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Bro i will try this, but it seems that with this solution i will not be able to use `document.find` and pass my other filters i would want to use in addition to the search?